# Extract the last three columns from a text file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a .txt file like this:

```
ENST00000000442 64073050    64074640    64073208    64074651    ESRRA


ENST00000000233 127228399   127228552   ARF5
ENST00000003100 91763679    91763844    CYP51A1
```

I want to get only the last 3 columns of each line.
as you see some times there are some empty lines between 2 lines which must be ignored. here is the output that I want to make:

```
64073208    64074651    ESRRA
127228399   127228552   ARF5
91763679    91763844    CYP51A1

awk  '/a/ {print $1- "\t" $-2 "\t" $-3}'  file.txt.
```

it does not return what I want. do you know how to correct the command?

Answer (score 5):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'NF{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'  OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
64073208        64074651        ESRRA
127228399       127228552       ARF5
91763679        91763844        CYP51A1
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation of command too now.(NOTE this following command is for only explanation purposes one should run above command only to get the results)

```
awk 'NF                  ###Checking here condition NF(where NF is a out of the box variable for awk which tells number of fields in a line of a Input_file which is being read).
                         ###So checking here if a line is NOT NULL or having number of fields value, if yes then do following.
{
print $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF###Printing values of $(NF-2) which means 3rd last field from current line then $(NF-1) 2nd last field from line and $NF means last field of current line.
}
'  OFS="\t"  Input_file  ###Setting OFS(output field separator) as TAB here and mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: It's good to add explanation why `NF` is required as the condition inside awk statement.  I think it is better to make the condition as `NF >= 3`.  Without it, we get wrong output when number of columns is less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed too

```
sed -E '/^$/d;s/.*\t(([^\t]*[\t|$]){2})/\1/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

With some piping:

```
$ cat file | tr -s '\n' | rev | cut -f 1-3 | rev
64073208        64074651        ESRRA
127228399       127228552       ARF5
91763679        91763844        CYP51A1
```

First, `cat` the file to `tr` to squeeze out repeted `\n`s to get rid of empty lines. Then `rev`erse the lines, `cut` the first three fields and reverse again. You could replace the useless `cat` with the first `rev`.